# Inspect Chai Assertion error returning [Object] [Object]

Tags: chai, sinon-chai, jsunit

I have a test

```
    let resultRedirects = {
        redirects: {
            fromPaths: [
                {
                    path: '/a-good/path',
                    type: 302
                },
                {
                    path: '/goodpath/Rocky%20Mountain%20PBS-HD,%20Create%20and%20V-me.',
                    type: 301
                }
            ],
            toPath: '/shows/default'
        }
    };
    let someFunc = sinon.stub();
    let wrapper = shallow(<Settings {...props} />);
    wrapper.instance().someFunc2({
            target: { value: '302' }
        },
    0);

    expect(someFunc).to.have.been.calledWith(resultRedirects);
```

The SomeFunc2 content is:

```
changeRedirectType = (e, index) => {
    const {
        redirects,
        redirects: { fromPaths },
        path
    } = this.props;
    let redirectsFromPaths = [...fromPaths];

    redirectsFromPaths[index].type = parseInt(e.target.value);

    changeSettings({
        redirects: {
            ...redirects,
            toPath: path,
            fromPaths: redirectsFromPaths
        }
    });
};
```

The response is

```
AssertionError: expected stub to have been called with arguments {
  redirects: { fromPaths: [ [Object], [Object] ], toPath: '/shows/default' }
}
{
  redirects: { fromPaths: [ [Object], [Object] ], toPath: '/shows/default' }
}
```

How can I inspect inside `[Object] [Object]` ?

Comment: What are the versions of `sinon-chai`, `sinon`, and `chai` are you using?

Comment: "sinon": "14.0.0",
        "sinon-chai": "3.7.0",
        "sinon-chai-in-order": "0.1.0",

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue. I can print the nested object.

Comment: `someFunc` is a `sinon.stub()` and I have a `wrapper.instance().someFunc2` which calls `someFunc`

Comment: You can see the answer I have deleted, can't reproduce it. Can you edit your question with a minimal, reproducible example?

Comment: I've updated the question. I didn't thought  `someFunc2` was relevant but I've posted all the context now.

Comment: Can you give a link in playground to your deleted answer because I can't see it anymore and I didn't had the chance to save it.